# Did my tokens land in an exchange walllet... or in a black hole?

Tags: blockchain, wallets, address.transfer

About a month ago I misread a blog on Binance.us which stated that they now support Polygon (Matic).   I assumed that meant I could send any token on the Polygon network to my binance account.

So... I sent about $6,800 USDC to the deposit address provided to me by binance for my account.  After the tokens never arrived in my account I discovered my error.

When I made a similar error 9 months ago on another exchange, someone looked at my transaction hash and showed me that my tokens had indeed landed in a "wallet." That exchange is promising to return the tokens. But binance is telling me they can't help me.

I'm not sure I believe them, so I'm trying to figure out the chain of transfers. On polygonscan, the transfer is noted as "successful".

But I discovered an interesting address change. The "deposit" address provided to me by binance was formatted like this: 0x3166xxx1111xxxx11xxx0b8cbc0f8ca.

If I'm looking at the transaction hash correctly however, it says that the tokens went to 0x3166xxx1111xxxx11xxx0b8cbc0f8ca**761xx1x30**.

(note that I obfuscated some characters with x's and 1's. But the remainder are original).

So do you think that my USDC landed in binance's ledger/account/wallet?

Happy to send links to an established member of this community if you like.

I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Your tokens should be in a wallet that is owned by Binance.
Whether they can recover them for you depends on the type of wallet they have for depositing funds.

- If it is an EOA then they can simply use the same private key to send
  you the funds back on Polygon (does not mean they will do that
  though)
- If they use some kind of contract for that it will be harder    to
  recover funds. The only possible I know then would be to deploy
  the same contract with the same nonce and account on Polygon, then it
  should have the same address and your funds might be recoverable...

I dont think they would go through all that and it might not even be possible, if the Polygon nonce is too high.
As to why the tokens went to a different wallet, I can only imagine you copied something in the wrong way, reading the transaction on polygonscan should be pretty straightforward. If you like send me the hash and I will take a look.
Good luck communicating with Binance!

Comment: Thanks.  Is it safe to publish the transaction hash here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your reason for obfuscating your wallet address and not providing your hash precisely at a time when you need help to clarify your problem. Understand that in cryptography this is public and is just another transaction on the network.

As for recovering your funds, this is entirely possible, just for binance to want to recover.

The wallet address is unique and can be opened under various protocols (bsc, ethereum, polygon...). All that is required is that binance logs into your account under the matic protocol and your USDC-Poly will be there. In order to know exactly if the address is valid (if it is not a contract without some value removal function) and also about the receipts, you need to provide the hash.

Comment: Thanks.  This helps.   I'll add some notes below!

Comment: Very good! Enter into a contract with binance and they will know how to solve the problem. I know they take a long time sometimes, but they always do. Take the opportunity to mark my answer as the best question and give it an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both.  Last night I realized that when I first investigated my transfer (in a state of distress) I did not notice that the popup "deposit address" screen in my binance account did not have a white background large enough to contain all of the characters in the deposit address:

[image: binance.us deposit address as seen in my browser]

However when I looked at it last night, I noticed the extra "mystery" characters were there after all.  They had just had spilled over below the white space.   Just a css issue.

So... when I originally made the transaction I had indeed copy/pasted the full address given to me by binance.

From your answers I now understand that the transfer did go to my "deposit" address at binance.  The question now is whether or not I can convince them to go to the trouble of logging into my wallet under the matic protocol and returning the tokens.  Fortunately in the US there are some legal principles in my favor.

Again, I appreciate your help.